# Angular change detection slow

Tags: javascript, angular, ngzone

I have a large array that I am using in a component (component A) with `*ngFor` with a nested `*ngFor`.

Component B initialises a jquery plugin which registers a document `mousemove` event handler, I am using `this.zone.runOutsideAngular` to init the plugin and I am calling `this.ref.detectChanges()` in the callback as I need to update the UI on `mousemove` inside the component B.

Component A is not a child of component B.

As soon as the component A is rendered change detection becomes very slow. the array does not change and I am using the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` strategy for component A but when I fire `ref.detectChanges()` inside component B, `ngDoCheck` gets called on component A and I can see a noticeable jank on `mousemove`.

Is there a way to tell angular to completely ignore the large array of items in component A and allow me to handle when the UI should be updated? I thought that using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` would give me what I need but I have tried removing all `@Input()`s from component A and anytime I call `this.ref.detectChanges()` inside component B it is still firing `ngDoCheck` and it is obvious that this is very slow.

I can scroll through the list of items no issue, but it is when I am triggering the `detectChanges` inside the `mousemove` on component B that is causing the issue. I know I could manually update the DOM but I think this would just be a workaround as it would only address the jank on mousemove and not the issue around the change detection being slow.

Comment: use 'trackBy : yourTrackByFn' in *ngFor . This will solve your issue, as whenever ChangeDetection happend it execute life cycle event for that component every time which impact on performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got to the bottom of this issue.

The problem was that inside component A for the nested *ngFor I was using a child component to render each sub item which meant that although I was using the ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush strategy, it still required a ref check for each item.

I have now moved the html from the child component into component A directly and this has had a huge impact on performance.

Answer (score 1):

`this.ref.detach()` to remove the detector from from the tree completely, that should stop the checking. Then you can still call `detectChanges` to do it manually, and `reattach` to bring it back online.

Maybe also debouncing the mousemoves (rxjs debounceTime()) might help, unless you really need to track every mousemove?

One more optimization if you already didn't, add `trackBy: yourTrackByFn` to the ngFor(s).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have forgot to mention I have tried detach which didn't help.